# Symfony Generating Specific Entities from the Database

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a larger database and I'd like to create entities for 4 tables. I'v been referencing this [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)  but it's not help quite getting me where I want to be.

### Step 1 - Import From Database

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
```

**Question Here:** Can you import specific tables? or all tables that start with 'Abc%'?) What command would do this?

### Step 2 - Convert the import to Annotaction|Yml|XML

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
```

**Problem here:** Even if I delete the imported files and leave the specific orm.xml I'm interested in, they still seem to affect this command. Is there a cache to clear or something??

### Step 3 -- Create the Entities

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

I haven't had any problems here.. However, getting to this point requires creating and deleting a lot of unnecessary files which is a real headache from a version control perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the steps should be done in below arrange and you need to use `--filter` for the specific table:

**Step1**

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation  /src/App/MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine --from-database --filter="table_name"
```

**Step2** Now you can apply importing

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AppMyBundle annotation --filter="table_name"
```

**Step3**

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppMyBundle --no-backup
```

Comment: Just be careful about `--filter` which is sensitive and it will filter all tables start with the phrase after `--filter`

Comment: Your step 1 is giving me "No Metadata Classes to process.". I've seen this error before. I'm not sure what to make of it. Should your step 1 be Step 1-B? I should still import the files from the database.. correct?

Comment: In this case you need to retrieve the metadata instances with the `DatabaseDriver` check the doctrine documentation [http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering] I think you need to put the path of `doctrine/config/metadata/orm` in the first step